# Import Image with Drag and Drop as Plane

Tags: rendering, mesh, import, image

I will import a lot of images to my project. Drag and drop is easiest way to do that for me. But if I drag and drop any image to my screen it been importing as background reference by default. How can I change this setting to "drag and drop image as plane that visible to render"? I don't want change visibility setting for each image every time. I want drag, drop and render.

Comment: Hello :). I don't think that's currently possible. However, you can drag-drop the images, and then convert all at once into Images as planes.

Comment: And direct link to the addon: https://github.com/danielenger/Empty-to-Image-Plane

Answer (score 0):

To import a lot of images at once ... it is much faster to use included addon **Images as Planes**, just enable it in User Preferences. Addon imports multiple images, you can set a basic material and set distance between images to bring them organised

Note - by drag&drop you import only one image per drag, then you will have to convert Empties to Planes (as pointed by Jachym Michal)